# A representation problem involving strict partition numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, partitions

For each positive integer $n$, let $q(n)$ denote the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of distinct positive integers. We call those $q(n)\ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$ *strict partition numbers*.
The sequence $q(1),q(2),q(3),\ldots$ is available from http://oeis.org/A000009. It is known that $$q(n)\sim\frac{e^{\pi\sqrt{n/3}}}{4(3n^3)^{1/4}}\qquad \ \text{as}\ \ n\to+\infty.$$

In 1996 P. Erdos and M. Lewin [Math. Comp. 65 (1996), 837-840] proved that each positive integer can be written as a sum of some elements of the set $\{2^a3^b:\ a,b=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ with no one dividing another. Motivated by this, we formulate the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Each positive integer $n$ can be written as a sum of strict partition numbers $q_1,\ldots,q_k$ such that $q_i\nmid q_j$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots,k$ with $i\not=j$.

I have verified this for all $n=1,\ldots,1350$. For example,
\begin{align*}1344&=8+76+1260,\\ 1345&=10+222+1113,
\\1346&=12+18+38+296+982\end{align*}
with $8,10,12,18,38,76,222,296,982,1113,1260$ strict partition numbers.

**QUESTION**. Can one find a counterexample to the above conjecture? Any possible way to prove the conjecture?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: I've checked up to 40000000 without finding counterexamples.

Comment: Dear Peter, many thanks for your further verification.

Comment: Dear Peter, I can hardly imagine how you could verify the conjecture up to $4\times10^7$. Can you show your program?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pjt33/f7a02d51d2f3c76aef2710cc0ab5e8ef